# Upload video on twitter Finalize api getting 400 error

Tags: android, twitter

I'm trying to upload a video which of 20 sec and it meets with all requirements of twitter specifications. In finalize request I'm getting BadRequest error. Could any one please help me.

WORKING: 
1) Init - get media_id
2) Append segment 0 - get 204 status code
3)Finalize - Returns Bad Request with 400 error code.

Comment: Did you figure this out?